# link_to with optional params not generating proper URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to link to the previous page (if available) and the next page (if available). The links show up in the right circumstances, but I cannot get them to link to the proper URL.

I've tried a number of methods to this approach:

```
<%= link_to 'Prev', url_for(params), class: 'ladder-nav-button pull-left' if has_prev_page? %>
<%= link_to 'Next', ladders_path(params), class: 'ladder-nav-button pull-right' if has_next_page? %>
```

In addition to things like hardcoding the values:

```
<%= link_to 'Prev', url_for(region: 'all', page: 1), class: 'ladder-nav-button pull-left' if has_prev_page? %>
```

I always end up with a link to /ladders, and not /ladders/all/1 or something like that.

The params are there. I can print them out on the page, but the links fail. Here is the relevant route (from rake routes):

```
ladders GET /ladders(/:region(/:page))(.:format) ladders#show {:page=>1, :region=>"all"}
```

The region and page are optional, but default to 'all' and 1 if not specified.

Where have I tripped myself up at? Is there some "gotcha" with optional params?

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`url_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for) -- why don't you use the path helper?

```
<%= link_to ladders_path(region: params[:region], page: params[:page]) %>
```

Comment: I've tried both url_for and the ladders path helper. Both end up with the same result. Whether I pass params, or (region: params[:region]) or a hardcoded value like (page: 1), the result is the same: '/ladders'